# Xamarin forms APK size increases after project was placed in tfs?

Tags: forms, xamarin, tfs

I am facing different issues in my Xamarin forms project.

Initially, my APK size is 14mb if download from Google play store, after keeping the project in TFS, suddenly the APK file size 20mb.

Why? any additional files will be generated by TFS in solution?

Comment: do you compare the size that is shown on a device with one that you have sent from PC?

Comment: yes sir.  case1: long back my app APK size 19 MB after archive ,same apk if publish at playstore then it was showing 14 MB only (I thought play store optimizing apk packages based on user mobile configuration).-------------------Case2: I moved my project into TFS , I generated apk ,19MB same as previous in size,but when apk moved into google playstore,playstore also showing 19MB to users  why??

Comment: My initial thoughts were that when you download an app it shows its unarchived size, so it may drastically vary between the one that you uploaded.